# How to enable PascalCase for enum values in the Swagger UI

Tags: asp.net-core, enums, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

What kind of configuration is necessary for Swashbuckle to display the enum values exactly as they are in the back-end, in PascalCase?

I am not looking for a global change, everything else works and looks great, just the enums.
A link to official documentation would be great!

- .NET Core 2.1
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.6.3
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters 5.1.2
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft 5.6.3

[image: camelCase enum values in Swagger UI]

[image: PascalCase enum values in C#]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo worked:

I used：

- .NET Core 2.1
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.6.3
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters 6.0.0
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft 5.6.3

[image]

Startup.cs:

ConfigureServices:

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings()
                );
            services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

Configure:

```
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("TestPriority")]
        public IActionResult TestPriority(List<Priority> p)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Priority:

```
public enum Priority
    {
        Primary_Image=3,
        Search_Image=9
    }
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Considering that DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings [is now deprecated](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/97ae7826b81fc81843dbdf529e9ad3f2bd39f1e4/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SchemaGenerator/SchemaGeneratorOptions.cs#L40), what helped me is the following code based on the intellisense suggestion:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
    {
        new StringEnumConverter{ NamingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy() }
    };
});
```